# Failed to load environment variable value into SSIS package variable (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have to load the value of an environment variable (let's say computer name, or other one) into an user defined variable used in a SSIS package, at flow level.
  I went to SSIS menu -> Package Configurations-> checked "Enable Package configurations" -> clicked "Add" -> Next -> then at "Configuration types" have selected "Enviroment variable" -> selected the needed eviroment variable -> next -> at "Select target proprety" i have selected from objects my variable and for property atribute - the value field.
  As a result it should have loaded my variable with the exact same value that envoirment variable selected (let say "computer name") had. But it does nothing! What do I do wrong?
  Any hints?

Best regards,

Comment: Sometime you need to `restart` your system or try to open ur BIDS again in order to get the `environment variable` in `SSIS` configuration wizard

Comment: I tryed this even on different computers using both VS 2008 and older verssions and same problem.

Comment: Check this link out http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/07/environment-variable-in-ssis-not-being-recognized/

Comment: Thanks a million praveen! It worked. Just needed to close and reopen project.

Comment: Great that helped u !